# How do you determine the center coordinate of an ellipse drawn using openCV?

Tags: opencv, drawing

On line 151 in [this program](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/camshiftdemo.cpp?rev=4234) it draws an ellipse:

```
ellipse( image, trackBox, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA );
```

How do I figure the center coordinate of the ellipse that was drawn after line 151?

According to [this page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/drawing_functions.html) an ellipse has a "center" property but I cannot figure out how to access it.

Would appreciate if someone can guide me how to get this center property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "trackBox" in the code is

> **RotatedRect**

class object type. So you can access the center co ordinates by the following way

```
trackBox.center.x 
trackBox.center.y
```

Add the following line of code after the line number 151 and see the center for visualization

```
ellipse( image, trackBox, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA );
circle(image,trackBox.center,5,Scalar(0,255,0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to check docs?

Ellipse is drawn with RotatedRect as you see in code. Here you have it: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rotatedrect#RotatedRect

**RotatedRect has center. So just `yourRectName.center`**